# Fedora won't boot after installing Nvidia drivers

Tags: fedora, drivers, grub2, nvidia

I followed [this](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/fedora-17-nvidia-guide/) tutorial about Nvidia drivers installation and I accidentally forget to do 5th point (disabling nouveau drivers), so now I can't boot my system. I know I am idiot but is there anything I can do to fix this?

**EDIT**

My boot options are (I don't if this is correct or not)

```
Fedora (3.8.9-200.fc18.x86_64)
other two with different version
```

When I press <kbd>e</kbd> to any of these I get lines setparams, then indenticated load_video, setgfxpayload, insmod 3x, set root, then if-else, linux, initrd. There is no line starting with kernel unfortunately.

Ok, I was able to unistall the drivers so I could boot with nouveau again.

Comment: Try pressing `a`, not `e`

Comment: It _has_ happened that nVidia drags their feet while kernel/X move on, and the combination just doesn't work at all. As Fedora agressively moves forward, this has been rather common.

Comment: `a` is not working, I can press only `e` to get inside that configuration file I've described above

Comment: Sorry, I am on a Fedora 17 system which seems to be booting with GRUB Legacy (e.g, 0.97).  You are likely booting with GRUB2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can boot into **single user mode** or **text-only mode**, make the necessary changes, and then boot back into graphical mode.

You can force booting into a specific mode when first turn on your computer by appending a number to the end of the `linux` line in GRUB2 (or the `kernel` line, in GRUB Legacy).  When you boot your computer, press <kbd>e</kbd> at the GRUB screen (the screen where you select which kernel you want to boot).  This will produce a GRUB menu editor containing the selected boot commands.  Find a long line that begins with `linux`.  At the end of the line, add a number corresponding to the mode you want to boot:

```
1 - Single User Mode
3 - Text-only Mode
5 - Graphics Mode (Usually the default mode)
```

For problems with a graphics driver, it's usually sufficient to boot into text-only mode (i.e., 3).  From here you can log in as your normal user, then become root and perform any administrative tasks that you need.  This includes uninstalling the nVidia driver or recreating the initramfs as per the tutorial.

**See Also** (with screenshots): http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/howto-change-runlevel-on-grub2/

---

Alternatively, depending on how far your system makes it in the boot process, you may be able to access a text-only **console** without changing any boot parameters.  Boot your system as normal and wait for it to make it as far as it goes.  Then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>.  If your system has booted to a sufficiently advanced state and is not hung, you should then see a login prompt.  Here you can log in as your normal user, become root, and then perform any administrative tasks to finish installing the nVidia driver.

Comment: I tried that (ctrl + alt + F2), didn't work. Please see my edit, I tried to follow your steps but there is no line starting with `kernel`.

Answer (score 2):

Boot to single user mode by appending '1' (without the quotes) to the GRUB kernel command line, blacklist nouveau and reboot.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following at the grub menu.

#### 1. hit any key during boot to access the grub menu

[image: ss1]

#### 2. edit the boot options

Hit the "e" key to edit the boot options.

[image: ss2]

#### 3. edit kernel boot options

Using the arrow keys arrow down to the kernel line. Hit the "e" key again to edit the boot options to the kernel.

[image: ss3]

[image: ss4]

#### 4. Add the run level

Add a number <kbd>1</kbd> to the end of the kernel options, and hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

[image: ss5]

#### 5. Boot the kernel

Hit the <kbd>b</kbd> key to boot the kernel.

[image: ss6]

[image: ss7]

Comment: As @IBr pointed out, this is not working on newest (18) Fedora

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is that Fedora does not use sysV system runlevels anymore (I had similar problem with Archlinux) so above examples doesn't work anymore.
Instead it uses systemd targets, which can be specified as following:

kernel=vmlinuz  parameter_and_so_on systemd.unit=multi-user

multi-user boots into what is equal to sysV 3 runlevel. If that not helps use: `systemd.unit=rescue`
Which is similar to SysV 1 runlevel.

When you done fixing just delete this from the end of the line. To switch on the run to graphical target when you done fixing run: 
`systemctl start graphical.target` Or just reboot and remove parameter in grub command line.

EDIT:
I'd seen that there is no in my system (as in askers too) `kernel=` cmd line I think correct line to add this should be either `linux=` or `intrd=`

Comment: That should be it, I know that Fedora does use `systemd` now. But where do I specify this?Anywhere in the file which I can edit?

Comment: Directly with `e` on boot entry see my EDIT in which lines to append this: either `linux=` or `initrd=`. I just can't remember exactly which.

Comment: If you see a `linux=` line, it would be that one.  Not `initrd=`

Answer (score 0):

Hold down `shift` when you start the machine. The grub menu should shortly appear. Press `e` Use arrow keys to navigate to the end of the `linux` line, and append the following `modprobe.blacklist=nouveau` Press `CTRL + x`. When you get back into the system, look for the blacklist files.
`/etc/modprobe.d` is a good bet. When you find where to put a blacklist file, or you can just add this line to an existing blacklist file `blacklist nouveau`  blacklist the module.

Answer (score -1):

Please install kernel-devel and after that, run command "akmods --force" with root permission. After reboot, it will be working well.

Comment: Could you [edit] this post to elaborate on how it would help with the OP's problem? At least personally, I fail to see the connection.