# Change monitor settings before gnome login

Tags: fedora, xorg, gnome, multi-monitor

I am attempting to use Fedora on a laptop with a broken screen connected to an external monitor. At what I assume is the login screen, I only see a solid grey screen. I am unable to log in because the computer is displaying the login box on the broken screen. Strangely, Fedora automatically mirrored the screens when I was booting from a live disk. Is there anyway I can change the monitor settings without logging in?

Extra information: Fedora 18 GNOME, lenovo ideapad U350.

Answer (score 1):

## Runtime Solution

One solution is to drop to a tty console (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>) and run `xrandr` to change the display settings to clone mode.  Run the command once with no options to find the names of the connections.  Look for a line that looks like

```
eDP1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 282mm x 165mm
```

Here the connection is named `eDP1`.  Set the working monitor to display the same content as the broken one with something like

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --auto --output VGA --auto --same-as eDP1
```

Then you can switch back to the graphical mode (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>) and the display should be cloned.

---

## Persistent Solution

You can achieve a persistent solution by creating an xorg.conf file with the clone option set.  Write the following lines to file and move it to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-clone-mode.conf`

```
Section "ServerLayout"
        Option "Clone" "On"
EndSection
```

I haven't tested it, but if this configuration is complete, the monitors should be cloned the next time you boot.

Comment: I tried the first solution, and xrandr gave the message "can't open display." When I rebooted after trying the second one, the monitor shows nothing, and ctrl-alt-F2 does nothing.

Comment: I see.  I should have tried running xrandr outside of an X session; I can see now why that doesn't work.  The behavior for the second solution is strange--even if something is wrong in 20-clone-mode.conf, you should still be able to access a console with ctrl-alt-F2.

Comment: You can still gain access to your system by changing the boot target from the GRUB2 menu that shows right when you turn on your computer.  See this answer http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74088/34796.  Once you boot into "multi-user" mode, you can delete the 20-clone-mode.conf file and you should be able to boot like you were before.  If you're feeling ambitious, you can check the X logs in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old` for lines that near the end that are errors (containing `(EE)`) and we can try to figure out what was wrong with the configuration file.