# Fedora 25 doesn't boot after removing nvidia driver

Tags: fedora, boot, drivers, nvidia

I got nvidia 970 gtx made by evga in my desktop PC. I was using Fedora 25 for almost a month without any problems. I had drivers installed following instruction from [rpm fusion](https://rpmfusion.org/Howto/nVidia) howto.

```
dnf install xorg-x11-drv-nvidia akmod-nvidia "kernel-devel-uname-r == $(uname -r)"
dnf update -y
```

But live cannot be so simple! Yesterday I made a system update and turned off the machine. Today when it booted I saw a low-resolution mode, completely without nvidia graphic support. I chose other kernels from boot menu: the same.

I tried reinstalling nvidia drivers as in above posted howto also without result. Then I removed nvidia driver completely with

```
dnf remove xorg-x11-drv-nvidia\*
```

and did reboot. Now I ended with my desktop in a state that it doesn'n boot at all. After choosing the kernel in `grub` monitor goes blank in a moment and I cannot even go to terminal with `ctrl+alt+F2`.

In `grub` menu I tried `rescue` option, which leads me to kind of limited console, but I cannot install driver from there due to lack of internet connection in that mode.

I was reading some old [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74077/fedora-wont-boot-after-installing-nvidia-drivers) which explained how to enter text mode, but it was in pre `systemd` era.

So... The question: how can I boot in this situation into text mode with internet support on `Fedora 25` and `systemd` to be able to install drivers? Or is there any other easy way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that solution was to edit boot option by clicking `e` and add `nomodeset` at the end of line starting with `linuxefi`.